# How to sort matrix column values then rows?

Tags: c#, linq

For example this matrix:

```
3 2
2 2
1 2
```

Writed as this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> inputRows = ...;
```

Must become:

```
1 2
2 2
2 3
```

So, all biggest numbers will be concentrated in the down right corner.
First, I need to sort **column numbers** (not entire columns), which is pretty easy to do:

```
var result = inputRows.Select(x=> x.OrderBy(y=>y));
```

After this step matrix will become:

```
2 3
2 2
1 2
```

But how do I sort out entire rows with LINQ?

**PS** Im not interested in fixed arrays solutions.

Comment: why LINQ? i would set arrays to be col1, col2 etc to split them out, sort the columns, and then put them back together.

Comment: Define *matrix*

Comment: matrix is `int[,]` `int[][]`, `List<List<int>>` or some class?

Comment: Sorry, I described and updated question.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it's a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` as per the question

Comment: you are actually ordering by row first.. in your current example

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The OP is ordering the sub collections which one can consider rows, but the items in the rows would make up the columns, and that's what the OP means.

Comment: @mjwills Why would that matter?

Comment: You can use the overload of  `OrderBy` that takes an `ICompare` and pass in one that compares each value in the two `IEnumerable<int>` "rows" being compared until you find a difference.

Comment: Wait, is it just a coincidence that your data looks like the values in each row was sorted and then the rows where sorted or do you just want all values sorted?  Basically should {{ 5, 1 }, { 3, 2}} sort to {{1, 5}, { 2, 3}} or {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}?

Comment: @eocron what if you will have `{{2,1}, {3,2}, {2,4}}`? what is expected output in this case?

Comment: @juhar sorry for misunderstanding, the First one is correct.

Comment: @eocron you should extend you input & output as it is **extremely** unclear what is it that you are asking for

Comment: there are many different ways to sort a matrix based on what you require. you didn't put enough data to clarify that. that's why many answers got deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a row comparer. We'll keep in mind that all rows have same length:

```
public class RowComparer : IComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public int Compare(IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y)
    {
        // TODO: throw ArgumentNullException 
        return x.Zip(y, (xItem, yItem) => xItem.CompareTo(yItem))
                .Where(c => c != 0).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And use it for sorting:

```
inputRows.Select(r => r.OrderBy(x => x)).OrderBy(r => r, new RowComparer())
```

Output for your sample:

```
[
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 2, 3 ]
]
```

Comment: I thought this is what the OP wanted, but after clarification they actually want something different.  The data just happens to sort correctly this way too.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what the OP wants as they have contradicted themselves in comments to other questions.

Comment: Apparently this is what the OP wants.  Carry on.

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I looked for =)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
var result = inputRows.Select(row => row.OrderBy(col => col)).OrderBy(row => row.Sum());
```

It's not clear how do you want order rows: by the whole row or by each cell?

Comment: Your solution will be invalid in this case: <3 2><4 1> It will output: <2 3><1 4>

Comment: @eocron Maybe specify the requirements instead of just expected output

Comment: You cannot just sum up the values.  You have to compare the first values and if they are the same then the next and so on.

Comment: @EpicKip Umm, I already specified that all biggest numbers should be in down right corner?

Comment: @eocron so that means the left number (after its sorted to be the smaller of 2) has nothing to do with the row sorting>? Thats useful to specify though